How to programmatically convert USD to MATIC in a Node.js application using Stripe without traditional exchanges or Mainnet swaps?
I am developing a Node.js application where users subscribe and make payments in USD through Stripe. Once the USD amount is credited to my Stripe account, I want to convert this amount to MATIC cryptocurrency. I'm looking for a solution to programmatically handle this conversion within my application's backend.
I want to avoid traditional methods such as withdrawing the USD balance to a personal bank account and then using an exchange like Binance to perform the swap. Additionally, I'm not interested in using third-party APIs like 1inch or CoinDesk, as they conduct swaps on the Mainnet and focus on crypto-to-crypto transactions.
Is there a way to integrate such a conversion directly within the application, possibly via any lesser-known APIs or services that support direct USD to crypto conversion on side chains or similar environments? If so, how can I securely and efficiently implement this?
What I have did:
I have tried stripe embedded Onramp crypto conversions too, but this feature is new and in Beta phase and I'm getting an error on conversion that you can see in attach screen shot.
